# Multivariate Faà di Bruno's formula

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, multivariable-calculus, algorithms, analytic-combinatorics

I'm attempting to implement a computer algebra function using the combinatoric version of Faà di Bruno's formula presented by Michael Hardy in [Combinatorics of Partial Derivatives](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601149) that "collapses" partitions to account for multiple variables. The paper is mostly very well-written and intelligible (its examples are used in the Wikipedia article) but there's one thing I'm unclear about.

To give an example:

[image]

I do the following:

- Compute the integer partition of the order represented as nested sequences
- Take the unmixed partial of f at the order corresponding the number of blocks in each partition
- Compose it with g
- Multiply the composition with the mixed partials of f corresponding to the blocks in the partition
- Sum the functions corresponding to each partition

I'm currently distributing the multiplication at each order/partition rather than collapsing partitions and multiplying by a scalar, so I'm duplicating some work but am just trying to get it correct right now).

I think the problem is that I'm misunderstanding the composition at each order, i.e. that f'''(y) in Hardy's example is *not*, if fact, the unmixed second-order partial of f composed with g. I just can't think of anything else that could be meant by notation like f''(y)(dy/x1 * dy^2/dx2xdx3).

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well you confuse me at two points: (a) you talk of "unmixed partial of $f$" -- but $f$ is just a function of one variable; and (b) you talk of "the mixed partials of $f$ " --but surely you mean "the mixed partials of $y$". I think you should distinguish carefully between $f$ a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ , and $F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n):=f(y(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n))$ a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician yes I assumed that's where my confusion lies. If I think about this in terms of the chain rule where both f and g can be multivariate then how do I get f(y) from g?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see where you tell us what $g$ is in your question. Is it $y(x_1,\dots,x_n)$?

Comment: The mixing of Leibniz's and Lagrange's notation is what's confusing me. It's clear from the traditional version of the formula that y is g and the partials are of g, but in that case both functions are assumed to be univariate.

Comment: But $f$ is univariate, $y$ is $n$-variate, $F$ [see my first comment] is $n$-variate. So $F$ has partials wrt the $x_i$, as does $y$; but $f$ just has plain old derivatives. Again, I think you should keep $f$ and$F$ distinct -- the tradition may be to confuse them but that's confusing.

Comment: To be precise: the LHS of your example is  less confusingly written as $\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2 \partial x_3}F(x_1,x_2,x_3)$

Comment: I understand that much, but my confusion is primarily about the RHS. I think it's possible I'm mistaking multiplication of, e.g. f'(y), with it being notation for the result of the mixed partial of F next to it—since y is the inner function in the composition. In terms of f'''(g), this would then just give me g in a form I could plug into f and then take the derivative of that as normal. Alternatively if y is taken to be f then the mixed partials on the RHS would represent its reversion, i.e. y where f'''(y) = 0.

Comment: On the RHS of the example the first term is the product of (i) $f'(y(x_1,\dots, x_n))$ [that is the derivative of the univariate function $f$ evaluated at the point $y(x_1,\dots, x_n)$] with (ii) the third partial derivative of the $n$-ary function $y$ with respect to $x_1,x_2,x_3$ evaluated at the point $(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_3)$.

Comment: When you say "*If I think about this in terms of the chain rule where both f and g can be multivariate*", could you spell that out in full? Are you trying to find $$\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2 \partial x_3 }f(x_1, x_2, x_3, g(x_1, x_2, x_3))$$?

Comment: That was at least initially my assumption, yes. But the point of confusion is over the apparently univariate function f.

Comment: Also, the actual form of the function shows the sum of the derivatives of f at the coefficients m. The section on the Wikipedia page is based on this paper: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Multivariate_version

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps if we look at the earlier terms it may help. [If it does not address your difficulty then I will happily delete it.]

We are looking at a composition $f(y(x_1,\dots,x_n))$. I think that this may be what is confusing you. I don't have any reference for a formula when $f$ is multivariate.

Then
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}f(y(x_1,\dots,x_n))
=
f'(y(x_1,\dots,x_n))\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}y(x_1,\dots,x_n)
$$
by the Chain Rule.

Next
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2\partial x_1}f(y(x_1,\dots,x_n))
=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\left(f'(y(x_1,\dots,x_n))\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}y(x_1,\dots,x_n)\right)
$$
and to this we apply the Product Rule and so
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2\partial x_1}f(y(x_1,\dots,x_n))
=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} \left(f'(y(x_1,\dots,x_n))\right)\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}y(x_1,\dots,x_n)
+\\
f'(y(x_1,\dots,x_n))\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}y(x_1,\dots,x_n)\right)
$$
Now apply to the first term the Chain Rule argument (we have $f'$ instead of $f$ and $x_2$ instead of $x_1$): we get
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2\partial x_1}f(y(x_1,\dots,x_n))
=
f''(y(x_1,\dots,x_n))\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}y(x_1,\dots,x_n)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}y(x_1,\dots,x_n)
+\\
f'(y(x_1,\dots,x_n))\cdot\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2\partial x_1}y(x_1,\dots,x_n)
$$

Now differentiate with respect to $x_3$. At each stage you need to use the Product Rule, and then on the $f^{(n)}((y(x_1,\dots,x_n))$ you must use the Chain Rule. Faà di Bruno's formula gives a combinatorial explanation of which products of partial derivatives of $y$ occur in the multiplier of $f^{(k)}(y(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

Comment: Are you just saying that f is univariate and the formula is generalized with respect to multiple variables in y? I assumed f could be multivariate as well. Is it something like that possible? And what type of situations come up when one would be working with functions in different dimensions to warrant this construction?

Comment: @SophiaGold $f$ cannot be multivariate because otherwise notations like $f''$ are not defined.

Comment: @SophiaGold. Yes, it's univariate here and in the paper you quote. If $f$ were a function of $y_1, \dots, y_m$ all functions of $x_1, \dots, x_n$ then the Chain Rule is more complicated and I don't know what the combinatorics are.

Comment: Thanks. And sorry for all the confusion. Given that restriction on f everything else makes complete sense. I suppose there are many systems that can be described in terms of a one dimensional function over higher dimensional spaces, e.g. certain types of transformations or cost functions in optimization problems, but I was having trouble imagining how functional composition fit into this. I suppose it's simply convolution, i.e. the "composition product?"

Comment: @ancientmathematician I'd like to mark your answer as accepted, but you would mind just adding a blurb about how I didn't realize f must be univariate and and you're not aware of a version of Faà di Bruno's formula that works on generalized composites?

Comment: @SophiaGold, for what it's worth, [there is a 1996 paper by Constantine and Savits](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1996-348-02/S0002-9947-96-01501-2/S0002-9947-96-01501-2.pdf) in which both $y$ and $x$ are multivariate.

Comment: [This newer paper by Tsoy-Wo Ma](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/download/259/pdf) provides a multivariate generalization of Hardy's combinatoric version of Faà di Bruno's formula.